# how to make tabata timer in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make countdown timer(user can adjust time) with 30 sec interval function.

It's my first coding!
I've done building interface....so on.

I need some guide with building timer.

The function is like this.

1. User can set time with +30sec, +1 min, +5min button
2. total time have to display like this. 00:00
3. Another '30sec count-down timer' below total time
4. '30sec count-down' repeats until total time end.(Like tabata interval timer)

That's it...

A little hint can help me a lot.

Thank you!

Comment: Start by learning about Swift Timer class, then write an simple  timer app and once that is done move on to making a tabata timer. [Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer), [article on Timer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer), [build app](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/build-an-stopwatch-with-swift-3-0-c7040818a10f)

Answer (score -3):

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { timer in 
    foo()
}
```

Use this timer initializer.